# How can I clone tables from one database into another in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to clone tables and views and the procedure ran without any errors but when I'm trying to call it, it gives me an error
The code is provided below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATABASE2.USERNAME.CLONE_TABLES_TO_SANDBOX(USERNAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  TAB_NAME VARCHAR;
  SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR;
  OBJ_TYPE VARCHAR;
  c1 CURSOR FOR (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TAB_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA AS SCHEMA_NAME, TABLE_TYPE AS OBJ_TYPE
    FROM DATABASE1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  );
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN c1 DO
    TAB_NAME := REC.TAB_NAME;
    SCHEMA_NAME := REC.SCHEMA_NAME;
    OBJ_TYPE := REC.OBJ_TYPE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DATABASE2."' || USERNAME || '_' || SCHEMA_NAME || '"';
    IF (OBJ_TYPE = 'VIEW') THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATABASE2."' 
                        || USERNAME || '_' || SCHEMA_NAME || '".' 
                        || TAB_NAME || ' CLONE DATABASE1."' || SCHEMA_NAME || '"."' || TAB_NAME || '"';
    ELSE 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATABASE2."' 
                        || USERNAME || '_' || SCHEMA_NAME || '".' 
                        || TAB_NAME || ' CLONE DATABASE1."' || SCHEMA_NAME || '"."' || TAB_NAME || '"';  
    END IF;
  END FOR;
  RETURN ('Tables copied successfully');
END;

CALL DATABASE2.USERNAME.CLONE_TABLES_TO_SANDBOX('USERNAME');
```

> SQL Error [1003] [42000]: Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR'
> on line 16 at position 5 : SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1
> at position 77 unexpected 'ANALYTICS'. syntax error line 1 at position
> 116 unexpected ''.

Comment: Temporarily change the SP to return the SQL statements, rather than executing them, and you should be able to debug where the issue lies

Comment: Appreciate your answer, however it didn't help. When I use CTAS instead of clone it works perfectly but when I use clone it gives me this erorr. Can you think of any reason why this happens?

Comment: How about updating your question with the SQL statements your code generated, so everyone else can see what it’s doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided code is failing when a view is cloned, which does not work.

**There is no syntax `CREATE VIEW target_view CLONE src_view` at [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view)**

> [CREATE  … CLONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone)
>
> Syntax
>
> **Databases, Schemas, Tables**
>
> ```
> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] { DATABASE | SCHEMA | TABLE } 
> [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <object_name>
> ```
>
> Other Schema Objects
>
> ```
> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] { STAGE | FILE FORMAT | SEQUENCE | STREAM | TASK } 
> [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <object_name>
> ```

Reproducing the case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE DATABASE1;
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST.VIEW1(col)
AS SELECT 1;
```

Cloning the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST.VIEW2
CLONE TEST.VIEW1;
```

> Syntax error: unexpected 'TEST'. (line 8)
>
> syntax error line 2 at position 16 unexpected ';'. (line 8)

Please note it is possible to clone entire schema, which could contain both tables and views.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TEST2
CLONE TEST;

SHOW VIEWS IN SCHEMA TEST2;
-- VIEW1
```

---

To copy tables the starting query should exclude views:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATABASE2.USERNAME.CLONE_TABLES_TO_SANDBOX(
                             USERNAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  TAB_NAME VARCHAR;
  SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR;
  OBJ_TYPE VARCHAR;
  c1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TAB_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA AS SCHEMA_NAME
    FROM DATABASE1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN c1 DO
    TAB_NAME := REC.TAB_NAME;
    SCHEMA_NAME := REC.SCHEMA_NAME;
    OBJ_TYPE := REC.OBJ_TYPE;

    LET sql_schema := ('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS DATABASE2."' || USERNAME 
                      || '_' || SCHEMA_NAME || '"');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_schema;

    LET sql_table := ('CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DATABASE2."' 
                      || USERNAME || '_' || SCHEMA_NAME 
                      || '".'  || TAB_NAME || ' CLONE DATABASE1."' 
                      || SCHEMA_NAME || '"."' || TAB_NAME || '"');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_table;
  END FOR;
  RETURN ('Tables copied successfully');
END;

CALL DATABASE2.USERNAME.CLONE_TABLES_TO_SANDBOX('USERNAME');
```